# Terminal: Open multiple profiles in tabs

Tags: command-line, launcher, gnome-terminal

I have terminal connections to various systems available from the Terminal if I use File->Tab->(system name). Sometimes I want to open a certain set of systems in tabs.

Is there a command I can use to launch multiple profiles in tabs on the Terminal? That way, each tab can have the different look and using the "default shell" setting I can run the command for remote access.

Answer (score 2):

You could install **konsole**. It can give you a random colour for each tab or you can have a different profile in each tab. It has a few more features than **gnome-terminal** but it can easily duplicate the latters functionality.